# How to set focus on last row of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, focus

I need to set focus on the last row of the grid after a grid row updation takes place. Can anyone help me out on this?

Below is my gridview,

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdViewForComment" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="Row_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Advanced search">
            <ItemTemplate>                                                         
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks for the edit abatishchev

Answer (score 0):

Check adding below code

grdViewForComment.Rows[19].Focus(); // RowIndex here.

grdViewForComment.Rows.Count-1